# Why is Perl's $? returning the wrong value for the exit code of a forked process?

Tags: perl, waitpid

Consider this trivial example of [fork()](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/fork.html)ing then waiting for a child to die in Perl:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use strict;
use warnings;

if (fork() == 0) {
        exit(1);
}

waitpid(-1,0);

print $?;
```

Running the script on Solaris 10 I get this result:

```
$ perl test.pl
256
```

I suspect the values of are being shifted upwards because when I do `exit(2)` in the child, the output becomes `512`.

I can't seem to find this documented in perl's [waitpid](http://perldoc.perl.org/dist/waitpid.html). Is this a bug on my system or am I doing something wrong?

Answer (score 24, accepted):

It's documented in the `$?` section of the [perlvar](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlvar.html) man page.

i.e. the real exit code is `$? >> 8`.

Comment: It's also covered in [perldoc -f system](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/system.html).

Answer (score 2):

The child might not even have gotten to call `exit`. As such, `$?` packs more information than just the `exit` parameter.

```
if    ( $? == -1  ) { die "Can't launch child: $!\n"; }
elsif ( $? & 0x7F ) { die "Child killed by signal ".( $? & 0x7F )."\n"; }
elsif ( $? >> 8   ) { die "Child exited with error ".( $? >> 8 )."\n"; }
else                { print "Child executed successfully\n"; }
```

This is documented more clearly in [`system`](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/system.html)'s documentation.